# Where exactly `hash == 1` performed in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

If we have the code like this:

```
class A {
  private hash = 0;

  public void test(){
    if (hash == 1) {
    //dosomething
    }
  }
}
```

Where exactly the compare performed ?

Here's my understanding:

1. Load hash into thread's stack, named r1.
2. compare r1 with literal 1.

Is it right ? In the meaning time, the hash in the heap could be changed ?

Comment: I think you are confused.  the hash is not the location in the heap, the hash is a value that denotes which objects are unique compared to each other.

Comment: @greedybuddha, I'm not sure, but IIRC all instance variables are located in heap, but their values' location may not.

Comment: The locations are definitely not, there is no way to access the heap location inside of java.

Comment: @greedybuddha, check out this [JLS 17.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1) : ** All instance fields, static fields, and array elements are stored in heap memory. **

Comment: I didn't say that they aren't stored in the Heap, they are.  I said there is no way to get the Heap addresses.

Comment: More likely `hash` is loaded into a register, which is then compared with the literal 1 in a single (maybe 2?) assembly command(s). Also, your example won't compile, it lacks a type on `hash`.

Comment: @greedybuddha Your statement that you can't get heap addresses is correct for primitives, but I believe the default `hashCode()` for `Object`s in Sun's JVM is the address. (And it appears you can use `sun.misc.Unsafe` to get the address regardless of the hash code).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360826/how-to-get-address-of-a-java-object, from JonSkeet himself... no :).  Or if you don't believe him, take a look at the Object code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 4):

Both field hash and constant 1 are loaded on stack. Then comparison is performed:

```
 ...
 GETFIELD A.hash : I    // push hash onto the stack
 ICONST_1               // push 1 onto the stack
 IF_ICMPNE L1           // pop the top two ints off the stack and compare them 
 ...                    // do smth
 L1
 RETURN
```