# How can I get address of an object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Simple question but I didn't see any answers on the internet. So, how can I get address of an object in Kotlin?

Comment: what do you mean by "address"?

Comment: @Roland I mean the object address in the memory

Comment: In general, you can't.  Why would you want to?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @gidds In some cases I want to track my object in memory for debugging purpose

Comment: You may want to read about memory addresses and Java... you should not access the memory address of objects directly... Some interesting questions about that: [Memory address of variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java), [How to get address of a Java Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360826/how-to-get-address-of-a-java-object), [Is there a way to get a reference address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820164/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-address) and just follow the duplicates from there on ;-)

Comment: @Roland thank for your references

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To identify an object during debugging, use `System.identityHashCode()`.

The address of an object can't be obtained on Kotlin/JVM, and it can also change as GC runs, so it can't be used to identify an object.

Comment: It's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: This solution is not relavant. The Hash is calculated on the value. So a = 1; b = 1 both got the same hash.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin in the JVM does not support pointers and so (apart from some jiggery-pokery with the sun.misc.Unsafe class) there is no way to obtain a variable's address.

However, Kotlin/Native (at least back in January 2018) does support pointers to enable it to interoperate with C code. The following program shows how to obtain the address of a variable which has been allocated on the native heap. It does not appear to be possible to allocate a variable at a particular address.

```
// Kotlin Native v0.5

import kotlinx.cinterop.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val intVar = nativeHeap.alloc<IntVar>()
    intVar.value = 42
    with(intVar) { println("Value is $value, address is $rawPtr") }
    nativeHeap.free(intVar)
}
```

results in:

```
Value is 42, address is 0xc149f0
```

Comment: If you really want the address of an object inside the JVM please refer to [How can I get the memory location of a object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060215/how-can-i-get-the-memory-location-of-a-object-in-java) or [Is there a way to get a reference address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820164/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-address)