# How can I find address of data in my system storage in Kotlin language?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have var (For example var a : Int =0 )in kotlin and I want a see my data address in my storage and where did it save ?

Answer (score 1):

please check this . possible duplicate here:

[How can I get address of an object in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089357/how-can-i-get-address-of-an-object-in-kotlin)

You can get initial memory address with :

System.identityHashCode()

This address could be changed during the time.